# finding maximum distance using MatLab

Tags: matlab, function

Say I have a matrix `A` which is a n*3 matrix listing cartesian coordination of n points. What I am interested in is finding northPole and southPole which are basically two coordinates with maximum distance apart. I want northPole and southPole to have minimum and maximum z coordinates respectively and I want to use x and y coordinates to break ties. This problem is easy to carry out using loops but I wanna make my code efficient because matrix A is really BIG. So I need help in finding northPole and southPole using built in MatLab functions so that the code is efficient. Thank you!

Comment: `northPole and southPole which are basically two coordinates with maximum distance apart` This may be true for your data, but you do realize that this does not have to hold in general?

Comment: "I want northPole and southPole to have minimum and maximum z coordinates respectively" - so why not use `max` and `min` on the z coordinates?

Comment: @DavidK because he wants to "break ties"

Comment: Can you guarantee that the two coordinates with the maximum distance apart have a minimum and maximum z-coordinate, respectively? Or do you want to pick the maximum and minimum z-coordinates first, and out of this subset find two points with the maximum distance between them?

Comment: i want to pick the coordinates with max and min z first, after that use x and y to decide the poles.

Comment: So you're looking for two extremes at the z-axis, with maximum distance _between them_? Or is it the maximum distance between the x and y coordinates for each individual point? (Frankly, the former sounds more logical).

Comment: Hey guys please read the answer I posted, I am having issues with it. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

You described the answer yourself: first find the index of the min or max Z values, then use the smallest X & Y distance to break ties.

```
zmax = max(A(:,3));
zmaxNdx = find(zmax == A(:,3));
d2 = A(zmaxNdx,1).^2 + A(zmaxNdx,2).^2;
[~, d2minNdx] = min(d2);
northpoleNdx = zmaxNdx(d2minNdx)

zmin = min(A(:,3));
zminNdx = find(zmin == A(:,3));
d2 = A(zminNdx,1).^2 + A(zminNdx,2).^2;
[~, d2minNdx] = min(d2);
southpoleNdx = zminNdx(d2minNdx)
```

Comment: I am not sure if your calculation for d2 is what i am looking for. after finding zmaxNdx and zminNdx, how about I do this: sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)) and then find the points which minimize this expression.

Comment: @SahilChaudhary That is pretty much the equation I'm using. I assumed that x == y == 0 at the poles, so `x1` and `y1` would be zero. I also omitted the `sqrt()` as an optimization because you only need to find the smallest value and taking a square root does not change which is smallest.

Comment: Hey please read the answer I posted, I am having issues with it. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you propose won't actually find the two coordinates with maximum distance apart. For example, what if the two points with maximum distance have `z = 0`?

Here are two solutions, one will actually give you the two points with maximum distance apart, the other is the implementation of your northPole-southPole algorithm. Note that in both solutions, the function I give returns the indices of the candidate points, not the points themselves. You can get the points themselves by

```
north = A(iN, :);
south = A(iS, :);
```

## Solution 1: Find the two points with maximum distance apart

Try using the `distmat` function from the [file exchange.](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15145-distance-matrix/content/distmat.m) It takes an `N x D` array of points `A`, where `N` is the number of points, and `D` is the dimension, and returns an `N x N` array of distances `dist`, where `dist(i, j)` is the distance between `A(i,:)` and `A(j,:)`. `distmat` has 4 different algorithms you can use to generate the matrix, depending on which gives you the best performance.

You can use this function to create a distance matrix, and then use `max` to locate the candidates for maximum distance. Then you can break ties in whatever way you like.

In the following function, I find all points which have a maximum distance apart. If there are more than one pair, then I break ties based on the x-y distance between the candidates.

```
function [iN, iS] = poles(A)

% create the distance matrix
dist = distmat(A);

% find all candidate pairs of north and south poles
[~, iMax] = max(dist(:));
[iN, iS] = ind2sub(size(dist), iMax);

% If there is only one, you are done, otherwise break the ties.
if length(iMax) == 1
    return
end

%
% break ties by the euclidean distance of the x-y coordinates
% note that this may not result in a unique set of north and south poles,
% but you can always break further ties.
north = A(iN, 1:2);
south = A(iS, 1:2);

tieBreak = sum(abs(north-south).^2, 2);

[~, iMax] = max(tieBreak);

iN = iN(iMax);
iS = iS(iMax);
end
```

## Solution 2: Find the "north pole" and "south pole"

This solution also uses the `distmat` function. First it finds points that have the max and min z value. If there are no ties, then it stops. Otherwise, it finds the pair of 'north' and 'south' points that have the maximum distance, and tie-breaks as above.

```
function [iN, iS] = poles(A)

% find the min and max z values
[~, iMaxZ] = max(A(:, 3));
[~, iMinZ] = min(A(:, 3));
iMaxZ = iMaxZ(:);
iMinZ = iMinZ(:);

if length(iMaxZ) == 1 && length(iMinZ) == 1
    iN = iMaxZ;
    iS = iMinZ;
    return
end

nMax = length(iMaxZ);
nMin = length(iMinZ);

% put the north and south poles together
northSouth = A([iMaxZ; iMinZ], :);

% find the distance between them
dist = distmat(northSouth);

% restrict to only north-south pairs
dist = dist(1:nMax, nMax+1:end);

% find the maximum distance
[~, iMaxDist] = max(dist(:));
[iN, iS] = ind2sub(size(dist), iMax);

if length(iMaxDist) == 1
    return
end

% break ties by the euclidean distance of the x-y coordinates
% note that this may not result in a unique set of north and south poles,
% but you can always break further ties.
north = A(iN, 1:2);
south = A(iS, 1:2);

tieBreak = sum(abs(north-south).^2, 2);

[~, iMax] = max(tieBreak);

iN = iN(iMax);
iS = iS(iMax);
end
```

Comment: Hey please read the answer I posted, I am having issues with it. Thanks a lot! :)